# How to get current route name in react native using react navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I just want the name of the current route or screen in react-native which I can use in condtions. I am using react class based component.

Answer (score 5):

Keep a ref of your navigation container and then call `getCurrentRoute().name` on the reference:

```
class App {
  navigationRef = null

  render() {
    <NavigationContainer ref={ref => this.navigationRef = ref}>
       .....
    </NavigationContainer>
  }

  getCurrentRouteName() {
    return this.navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name
  }
}
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/ (I just converted the function based component syntax into the equivalent class component one)

Comment: This worked for me but it has a strong performance hit. Switching tabs/screens was almost instantaneous, not it takes a bit more than a second.

Comment: Update: The delay was caused by setting global state with Context API, it's not a router issue.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `name` property within the route props.

```
function ProfileScreen({ route }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the profile screen of the app</Text>
      <Text>{route.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop